# Discord.js Multi Line Embed Description

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make an embed Description with more lines can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you mean line breaking using `\n`?

Answer (score 3):

There are two easy methods:

### Method 1

Using `\n`

```js
embed = {
   "author": 'SefovskiLeaks',
   "description": 'First line\nSecond line\nThird line',
   ...
}
```

### Method 2

When using ` you can enter a new line **in the code**

```js
embed = {
   "author": 'SefovskiLeaks',
   "description": `First line
   Second line
   Third line`,
   ...
}
```

Comment: @SefovskiLeaks If this fixed your problem, I'd be happy if you mark it as accepted :)